# "we are some" or "we are a few"

Tags: grammaticality

I don't know what should I say between "we are some" or "we are a few"
in the sentence below.
Also can both be said, if so please educate me on when should I use each ?

We are some in my department having two computers.
or
We are a few in my department having two computers.

I'm contacting an other company to purchase a software to manage my two computers with one mouse and one keyboard.

(I'm a French Quebecker, google failed me, so as my Antidote software)
Thank you for the comments and the answer, I edited my questions to provide more context.

Comment: It looks like it should be something like "We are a few/some of those in my department..."

Comment: There's not enough context in your fragment to tell us exactly how you're trying to use ***few***. Adjectivally, *We [Scientologists] are few [and far between] in my department, having been subject to a purge on cult members last year.* Or as a noun, *There are a few of us here having / who have this problem.*

Comment: To me (and given that there is no full sentence) it sounds more likely that it should be ***There are*** *(a few / some) of us in my department* ***who are*** *having* . . .

Answer (score 1):

Neither of the given forms is correct. Correct forms that might convey the intended meaning might include:

> Some of us in my department are having a problem.
>
> A few of us in my department are having a problem.
>
> There are a few of us in my department who are having a problem.

These have pretty much identical meaning and usage, except that "some" could mean more than a few, indeed could mean a majority of the department.

If the intent is to identify the people in the department who are effected, one could say

> We are the ones in the department who are having a problem.

This goes better if adjacent speech indicates who "we" are.

> John, Mark, and I are upset. We are the ones in the department who are having a problem.

Another possibility is:

> We are among the few in the department who are having a problem.

This says that the problem is not widespread -- only a few have it, but that "we" are only a part of that few.

Comment: I edited my question. Are the given forms still wrong, if so why ? Thank you.